# PCNF of $(p_1 + p_3)(\neg p_2+p_3)$

Tags: logic

I know that PCNF of $(p_1 + p_3)(\neg p_2 + p_3)$ is $(p_1+p_2+p_3)(p_1+\neg p_2+p_3)(\neg p_1+\neg p_2+p_3)$
but I want to know how can I prove it with rules of logic. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know about maxterms?

Comment: yes I know about maxterms. I wanted to know the procedure that those maxterms were produces. I know how to produce the maxterms with the truth table. I want to know how can I produce them by applying the rules of logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**$(p_1\lor p_2)(\lnot p_2\lor p_3)$$\equiv [(p_1\lor p_2\lor(p_3\land\lnot p_3)][(p_1\land\lnot p_1)\lor\lnot p_2\lor p_3]$ as $p\land \lnot p\equiv F$ and $F\lor p\equiv p$. Can you express it now as the product of sums canonical form?

Comment: No, I can not. A term does not solve out.